# Olingo odata 2 structure and flow of work

Tags: odata, olingo

Recently I joined new company. In that company they are using odata 2 for REST API's and JPA for ORM.

Can any one explains how exactly this odata 2 olingo frameworks works. I am familiar with MVC, Spring MVC, RestController.

But I am not able to get this olinog odata 2 flow, to create project from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Spring MVC knowledge will not help you to understand Olingo framework.
A good start is reading [OData basics](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/) if are not familiar with this protocol.
Then you can play with Olingo. They have a great sample project, just follow instructions from the [documentation](https://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata2/sample-setup.html).
Investigating sample project + reading [examples](https://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata2/index.html) will help you to get familiar with Olingo quickly.